# How do I drop rows with zeros in Panda dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to take the average property assessment value for each zipcode (without counting the zeros). So I would have an average value for 02126 and an average value for 02130. I would like to drop all rows with 0 in AV_LAND. What is the best way to go about that in a pandas dataframe? Thanks in advance!

```
   ZIPCODE AV_LAND
0   02130   7900
1   02126   0
2   02126   20600
3   02126   520800
4   02126   20800
5   02127   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming `df` is your dataframe

```
df.loc[df.AV_LAND != 0].groupby('ZIPCODE').mean()
```

[image]

```
df.loc[df.AV_LAND != 0].groupby('ZIPCODE').mean().reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I should have clarified, I meant the average value pertaining to each each zipcode

Comment: Why are the header names in different rows btw?

Comment: @dancemc15 `ZIPCODE` is the name of the index in that final dataframe.